# projections of a polygonal line

Tags: graph-theory

Does there exist a closed nonempty connection of line segments $X$, joined by their endpoints in space so that for every co-ordinate plane, the union of the projections from $X$ to the plane is a cycleless graph?

Note: the cycle in question has a requirement of having at least 3 involved vertices.

thinking of the projection formula

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take $X$ to be the empty collection of line segments.

Comment: haha lol fixed the problem... could you help me out

Comment: @TheMathTroll: Then does a 2-cycle count? After projection it's just a graph with a single edge.

Comment: Fine, editing again. Cycle with at least 3 vertices involved

Comment: I think it's impossible if your cycle does not self-intersect, but I am too lazy to sieve through the numerous cases. Note that any two distinct points will project to distinct points except under at most one projection. That should with judicious choice of cases be enough to solve the problem I think.

Comment: Oh okay... Nice!